# File conversion - From Dataframe to Fixed Width File

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm reading a Fixed Width Text file and loading into a Dataframe, From the df i'm repositioning columns so I can write to a file with Fixed Width columns. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

#Read File from Target Directory

````
    for file in fileNames:
        if file.is_file():
            print(file.name)

#FWF to read file 
transfile = pd.read_fwf(file , skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=None, converters={0:str, 1:str}, keep_default_na=False,
widths=[
12,#ID  index1
12,#SURNAME  index2
7,#FIRSTNAME  index3
1,#MIDDLEINITIAL  index4
1,#GENDER  index5
8,#BIRTHDATE  index6
1,#Filler  index7....

# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
'recordType', 'ID','SURNAME','FIRSTNAME'...

#Paddle to Fixed Width per Column
df['DI']=tc61[0]
df['SURNAME']=tc61[1]
df['FIRSTNAME']=tc61[2]
df['MIDDLEINITIAL']=tc61[3]
df['GENDER']=tc61[4]
df['ID']=df['ID'].str.ljust(12," ").replace(np.nan, ' ')
df['SURNAME']=df['SURNAME'].str.ljust(12," ").replace(np.nan, ' ')
df['FIRSTNAME']=df['FIRSTNAME'].str.ljust(7," ").replace(np.nan, ' ')
df['MIDDLEINITIAL']=df['MIDDLEINITIAL'].str.ljust(1," ").replace(np.nan, ' ')
#Join all columns 
fixedWidthFile = order[order.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x:''.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
#Last step is to write to text File file = open("file.txt", "w+")
content = str(fixedWidthFile)
file.write(content)
file.close()
file = open("file.txt", "r")
content = file.read()
print("\nContent in file.txt:\n", content)
file.close()```
````

Comment: First of all format the code properly.

Comment: This is close enough but I need to remove spaces when joining all columns in df FixedWidthFile = df.to_string('FixedWidthFile.txt', index=False, header=False)